# How to stylize an image that is being pulled from an object array into a div

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I style an image that is being pulled from an object array.  When I pull the name from the object array it fits correctly into the div, but when I pull an image the size does not change to fit the size of the div. I have tried to change through CSS, but cannot seem to target it specifically. I've included the code as well, I also do apologize in advance I'm not sure how to include the image in the code snippet but any help on how I could target the image would be appreciated

```js
const guards = [
    { 
        name: 'Stephen Curry',
        img: '<img src="/images/curry.png"/>',
        stats: [
            {points: 24.5},
            {rebounds: 4.7},
            {assists: 6.5}
        ]
    },
    { 
        name: 'Ja Morant',
        stats: [
            {points: 22.2},
            {rebounds: 4.7},
            {assists: 7.3}
        ]

    },
    { 
        name: 'Damian Lillard',
        stats: [
            {points: 24.7},
            {rebounds: 4.2},
            {assists: 6.7}
        ]

    },
]


const forwards = [
    { 
        name: 'Lebron James',
        stats: [
            {points: 27.2},
            {rebounds: 7.5},
            {assists: 7.3}
        ]
    },
    { 
        name: 'Kevin Durant',
        stats: [
            {points: 27.5},
            {rebounds: 7.1},
            {assists: 4.3}
        ]

    },
    { 
        name: 'Giannis Antetokounmpo',
        stats: [
            {points: 22.3},
            {rebounds: 9.5},
            {assists: 4.6}
        ]

    },
]

const centers = [
    { 
        name: 'Nikola Jokic',
        stats: [
            {points: 20},
            {rebounds: 10.4},
            {assists: 6.2}
        ]
    },
    { 
        name: 'Joel Embiid',
        stats: [
            {points: 26.6},
            {rebounds: 11.3},
            {assists: 3.4}
        ]

    },
    { 
        name: 'Domantas Sabonis',
        stats: [
            {points: 14.8},
            {rebounds: 9.5},
            {assists: 3.9}
        ]

    },
]
const guardAContainer = document.getElementById('guards')
const forwardAContainer = document.getElementById('forwards')
const centerAContainer = document.getElementById('centers')
const guardBContainer = document.getElementById('guards-b')
const forwardBContainer = document.getElementById('forwards-b')
const centerBContainer = document.getElementById('centers-b')
const generateBtn = document.getElementById('generate')
let shuffleGuards,shuffleForwards,shuffleCenters
let currentGuardsIndex,currentForwardsIndex,currentCenterIndex

generateBtn.addEventListener('click', generatePlayers)


function generatePlayers(e){
    const shuffleGuards = Math.floor(Math.random() * guards.length)
    const shuffleGuardsB = Math.floor(Math.random() * guards.length)
    const shuffleForwards = Math.floor(Math.random() * forwards.length)
    const shuffleCenters = Math.floor(Math.random() * centers.length)
    const shuffleForwardsB = Math.floor(Math.random() * forwards.length)
    const shuffleCentersB = Math.floor(Math.random() * centers.length)

    // currentGuardsIndex = 0;
    console.log(guards[0].img)
    guardAContainer.innerHTML = guards[0].img
    // guardBContainer.innerText = guards[shuffleGuardsB].name
    // forwardAContainer.innerText = forwards[shuffleForwards].name
    // forwardBContainer.innerText = forwards[shuffleForwardsB].name

    // guardAContainer.innerText = guards[2].name
    
}

function comparePlayers(){

}
```

```css
h1{
    text-align: center;
}

h4{
    text-align: center;
}

span{
    color: red;
}

.main-container{
    display: flex;
    padding:20px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.box{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.box img{
    object-fit: contain;
}


.btn-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:60px;
    width:100px;
}

.btn{
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
    border:.5px solid black;
}

.pics-container-row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.pics-container-row img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NBA 3v3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/master.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>NBA 3 v 3!</h1>
    <h4>Click <span>Generate</span> button to bring randomize your two teams! Click <span>Compare</span> to see which of the two teams would win!</h4>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="team-a">
            <div id="guards" class="box"></div>
            <div id="forwards" class="box"></div>
            <div id="centers" class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons" class="btn-container">
            <button class="btn" id="generate">Generate</button>
            <button class="btn" id="compare">Compare</button>
        </div>
        <div class="team-b">
            <div id="guards-b" class="box"></div>
            <div id="forwards-b" class="box"></div>
            <div id="centers-b" class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pics-container-row">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/images/bron.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/images/curry.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/images/dame.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/images/durant.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/images/embid.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pics-container-row">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/images/giannis.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/images/harden.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/images/jokic.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/images/lavine.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/images/mitchell.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class name like this way

guardAContainer.innerHTML = guards[0].img

// Add this code
let img = container.querySelectorAll("img");
img.addClassName("new-class");

Comment: That doesn't seem to target the image. No matter how big or small i make the image it still comes out at its default size